# Mysql Counting Child Table Entries With Parent Table have some value=something

Tags: mysql

I am using this query to get total count of child a parent have with respected to a timeslot value of '8:00 am'

```
select count(c.id) from 11_Attendee a 
left join 12_Child c on c.pid=a.id 
where a.field64='8:00 am'
```

This query is taking too much long to fetch the count, any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: do you have indexes on your columns c.pid,a.id and a.field64?

Comment: do you have indexes, can you please show me the explained result(EXPLAIN QUERY).